# ¿Cómo terminar la ejecución del programa al ingresar valor específico en C?

Tags: c

He hecho el siguiente programa en el cual:

- se introduce un número
- comprobando en el vector dice que está o no está
- si está dice el lugar donde se encuentra.

Este es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int v[]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30};

    int i,x;
    char p='f';


    printf("\nintroduce un numero:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

   for(i=0;(p=='f')&&(i<15);i++)

if(v[i] == x){

p= 'v';
        }

if (p=='v')
        {

printf("el valor esta en el vector en la posicion %d",i-1);
        }

else if (p=='f')
        {

printf("NO");
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Lo que me gustaría poner para terminarlo es que  al introducir el valor `0` **finalice el programa**.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `return` para salir en cualquier momento del programa.

```
     scanf("%d",&x);

     if (x==0) return 0;

       for(i=0;(p=='f')&&(i<15);i++) 
...
```

Comment: ¿Y si lo que quiero es que me siga pidiendo números y comprobandolos hasta que meta un 0?, lo he intentado con el do-while y otros métodos pero me pasan dos cosas, que entro en un bucle infinito o ya no me sale la posición del número. gracias por contestarme.

Comment: @wifly entonces debes de hacer otra pregunta, ya que en esta preguntaste "como terminar la ejecición del programa al ingresar un valor", por favor decídete antes de pregunatr acerca de lo que quieres y/o necesitas

Comment: Yo añadiría que lo del `return` solo sirve si estás en el `main`